# how to check if the entered numbers in the fields are repeated

Tags: c++, vector, field, element

I'm doing a lottery project. I insert seven numbers into fields, the numbers cannot be repeated. I was wondering if I need to do this with a `for` loop or a `do while` statement? I just don't know how to check if next inputted number is not equal to first number. I have to input a number and check if it's equal in one step.

```
for(int y=0;y<numbers;y++)
{ 
    cout << "input a number from 1-39:  ";
    cin >> input[y];

    while(input[y] < 1 || input[y] > 39)
    {
        cout << "inputed number is not between 1 and 39 ";
        cin >> input[y];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a temporary array, which copies all the inputs, then go check if the inserted number already exists in the temporary array with the help of a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::set` instant of array.

```
vector < std::set > vec_set;
```

whenever you insert value in set just check `std::set.find()` and `push_back` in vector after getting all 7 value in set.

Comment: That syntax is totally made up.

Answer (score 0):

Put the numbers into a std::set until there are seven elements in the set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   set<unsigned int> Numbers;
   while( Numbers.size() != 7 )
   {
      cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 39 (" 
           << 7 - Numbers.size() << " left)" << endl;

      unsigned int Num;
      cin >> Num;

      if( Num < 1 || Num > 39 )
      {
         cout << "Invalid number entered: "<< Num << endl;
      }
      else
      {
         Numbers.insert( Num );
      }
   }
   unsigned int igralec[7];
   copy( Numbers.begin(), Numbers.end(), igralec );
}
```

If you're not familiar with the STL this is a good point in time to start with.

Comment: how can I set the field value? i was thinking to insert..     for(int i = 0 ; i < 7; i++)    before    cout <<"Please enter a number between 1 and 39.  and  
  num == igralec[i]; after Numbers.insert( Num );  is that okay?

Comment: @Aleks Jovanovič :  *num == igralec[i];* I do not know what do you mean by this. as long as you use *while( Numbers.size() != 7 )* you don't need a for loop. If a same number is trying to insert to a *std::set<>*, insertion will fail, and thus its size will not increase. Thats how its works.

Comment: I'm trying to set input values that i inputed into num to igralec[] field that has 7 fields

Comment: std: :copy( Numbers.begin(), Numbers.end(),  igralec );